# multline and mdframed bug

Tags: mdframed, multline

I do not think this bug has been reported anywhere. At least, I could not find such a report. Below is a piece of code to see the problem. The frame in the right margin is improperly calculated.

```
\documentclass[10pt,fleqn]{book}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm}
\usepackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed}
\newmdtheoremenv[backgroundcolor=red!10]{theorem}{Theorem}
\begin{document}
\begin{theorem}text\begin{multline}text\end{multline}text\end{theorem}
\begin{theorem}text\begin{equation}text\end{equation}text\end{theorem}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I think bugs are best reported directly to the author of the package. See [What is the best way to announce a bug in TeX-related software?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1773/2693)

Comment: Sorry, but direct bug reports don't belong here. Write a email to the author(s). You can also consider posting it to comp.text.tex in addition to that.